# How to get same textSize across Android devices?

Tags: android, font-size

I my Android app I have a `TextView` with a width of 50% of the screen width, and a height of 10% of the screen height. I've set the `textSize` to 44sp, but on big devices (screen size) it renders the text too small, and too big on small devices. How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781516/android-textview-size-in-different-screen-size

Comment: use dp intead of sp. SP means giving control to user. dp means fixed font size.

Answer (score 0):

use folder like for dimens.xml file

- values
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw720dp

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set both width and height of your TextView to `wrap_content` and use *sp* for your text size.

Setting your text size to 44sp with `wrap_content` should work pretty well for most devices.

If you still need to adjust certain devices (densities) you can extract your text size into its own `dimen` resource and override its value for default configurations, like shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali)